# How can i use vue-moment ( this.$moment) in Vuex?

Tags: vue.js

Hello I have a question about vue-moment. How to use in every component this.$moment when i can't use it on Vuex? When i try to make state like

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
moment : this.$moment 
)}
```

I get error TypeError:

> Cannot read property '$moment' of undefined

Comment: you may mark the answer as accepted that helped you, and you may remove the acknowledgment answer you just posted. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `moment` in the Vuex by added it, in your `store.js` file.

```js
import moment from "moment";
```

And then you can use it, in your `actions` and etc.
Take a look at my example [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-qw5pw)

Answer (score 2):

You do not have a reference to `this` when trying to create a Vuex store.

You can just add a reference to the import like this:

```
import moment from 'moment'
export default new Vuex.Store({ moment : moment})
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use moment by `this.$moment`, simply you need to install the moment via npm and tell Vue to use it globally

**install**

```
$ npm install vue-moment
```

**To tell vue to use it globally**

```
Vue.use(require('vue-moment'));
```

and then you can simply use `moment("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a")` in any component.

Check the docs **[here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-moment)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this **Vue.prototype.$moment** in *Vuex* *file*.